# Conditional access modifiers?

Tags: c#, dll

My company has a software product with a very large sized DLL (approx 11 MB) and I have been assigned the task to reduce its size by making two or three versions of the DLL to only allow provided lists of methods in each DLL. The current DLL has every method but most of our clients only use certain sets of methods depending on their industry.

I have the solution with 7 projects in it: two are C++ projects, and five are C#. Two of the C# projects call functions from C++ projects (using dllexport), I think it's called unmanaged code (please bear with me, I am a novice in this field so I don't know the terminology too well - in fact I just now found out that "public/private/protected/etc" are called "Access Modifiers"! :-) )

So far I have figured out how to define a solution-wide preprocessor constant to use with "#if". So far I have come up with the following to create three DLL:

For example, something like the following is in one of the .cs files:

```
#if DLL_FOR_INDUSTRY_A
public void method_A(int arg1)
#else
private void method_A(int arg1)
#endif
{
  for (int x=0; x<arg1; x++)
  {
  // code here;
  }
}

#if DLL_FOR_INDUSTRY_B
public void method_B(int arg1)
#else
private void method_B(int arg1)
#endif
{
  // code here;
}

#if DLL_FOR_INDUSTRY_C
public void method_C(int arg1)
#else
private void method_C(int arg1)
#endif
{
  // code here;
}
```

But my problem is that I have around 400+ methods in the entire DLL! Some methods will be common among new DLLs that I am supposed to create. Two of the new DLLs will represent software editions (think of it as "Standard" vs "Professional" editions.)  I also looked at using "**[System.Diagnostics.Conditional]**" but it doesn't work if a method is **"public method_A(int x)"** instead of something like **"public void method_A(int x)"**. If I add "void" in existing methods, it breaks a lot of other calls (nightmare!) Plus I'm not an expert in this field so I can't tell which way would be the better approach.

My question- does anyone have a better suggestion on how I should be doing this properly? Even better if someone can point me to the right direction on how such large DLL can be "conditionally" compiled so that I can set a preprocessor constant to change the DLL outcome. (I tried compiling with what I showed above (only covering around 15 methods instead of 400+, its a lot of work) but the DLL size didn't seem to change, not sure if unused methods are still getting compiled into the new DLL.)

Can Access modifiers be made "Conditional" in an easier way? (so that they don't show up in the output DLL.)

Please help!  I am using Visual Studio 2015 on Windows 7 & Windows 10.
My sincere gratitude to anyone that can give me some direction, I have been at this for the past 5 days including the weekend and yet I have no good solution. :-(

Comment: `public method_A(int x)` is not just "a method". It is a constructor.

Comment: Will making stuff private reduce the size of the DLL?

Comment: Why not use inheritance? You definitely don't want to do something like "if client == x... else if client == y..." - I worked somewhere where they did that and it was *horrible* to maintain.

Comment: @ Ed Plunkett : You maybe right, as I say in my post that so far it didn't seem like reducing the size, but if I put the whole function under conditional assembly, it breaks some other calls. So I'm still trying to figure out how to do this.

Comment: I've seen what @EJoshuaS describes too, and it was a horrorshow. I would have a very strong preference for breaking it up into multiple assemblies and shipping them the ones they need. I don't often go intransigent in meetings but I would be very forceful on this.

Comment: @ EJoshuaS  I'm going to google what "use inheritance" means, I'm still learning this all so currently I don't know how to do that. Thank you...  (By the way, the target DLL are not client-specific but industry-specific and product edition-specific, not sure if that makes any difference)

Comment: @EmbeddedDude If #if'ing out the whole method breaks something else, then the private method is definitely still in there and you're not reducing the size any. I had kind of a dim forlorn hope that maybe if it wasn't being called, the optimizer might sweep it away, but no chance in this case.

Comment: If removing something that's (supposedly) relevant only to Industry A breaks something that's (supposedly) only relevant to Industry B, then that would imply that either the method's relevant to both industries after all or there's an inappropriate dependency that needs to be factored out.

Comment: @Abion47 Is there a way to conditionally remove constructor (and everything attached to them) from a DLL? Thank you - I just now realized that it's a constructor! duh. :-)

Comment: making a lot of conditions doesn't seem ideal. just create 3 different assemblies with the methods they need.  you have 3 versions of smaller size. they can use any of 3 versions without needing to recompile things again.

Comment: @EJoshuaS Agreed, I think those are the constructors & methods which are common to two output DLLs which are product-editions, but not rest of the output DLLs.

Comment: @EJoshuaS Thank you again - I took up on your suggestion to use inheritance, I got twice as much done yesterday than previous five days combined and it already looks like a MUCH better solution! (Especially my need for two editions of output DLL looks like a piece of cake with it.) If you change your comment to an answer, I'll set it as the accepted answer.  Thank you everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using inheritance here rather than conditional compilation - for example, having a base class that holds common functionality used by all industries and implementations for different industries that contains industry-specific functionality. You can then split it up into multiple assemblies, giving everyone a DLL with the common functionality along with a second DLL that contains the code relevant to their particular industry.

You definitely do *not* want to do a lot of "if" statements to do the industry-specific stuff. I remember working for a company about 10 years ago that had code like

```
if (client == x) ...
else if (client == y) ...
else ...
```

Predictably, this quickly became very difficult to maintain. For the record, the code was written before I got there, so it wasn't my fault ;). In their case, they could've benefited from using the [Template Method Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern) instead of doing client-specific reasoning. (The [Strategy Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) and [Factory Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_(object-oriented_programming)) are both often very helpful in cases like this).